# Chebysev inequality proof

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(X,\Omega,\mu)$ be a measure space and let $f$ be an extended real valued measurable function defined on $X$. Proof that

$$
\mu\left(\{x\in X : |f(x)|\geq t\}\right)\leq \frac{1}{t}\int_X |f|~d\mu 
$$
for any t>0.

Then, conlude that the measure of the set $$\{x\in X : |f(x)|\geq t\}$$

is finite for every t

Comment: Did you tried to Google it?

Comment: Yes, but they usually proof it related to statistics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $A$ as $A=\{x\in X : |f(x)|\geq t\}$. Then we have

$$
\mu\left(\{x\in X : |f(x)|\geq t\}\right)=\int_{A} ~d\mu =\int_{X} \chi_A ~d\mu 
$$
where $\chi_A(x)=\mathbf 1(x\in A)$. Then we have:
$$
\mu\left(\{x\in X : |f(x)|\geq t\}\right)=\int_{X} \chi_A  ~d\mu \\
= \int_{X} \frac{t}{t}\chi_A ~d\mu  \leq \int_{X} \frac{|f|}{t}\chi_A ~d\mu  \\
\leq \int_{X} \frac{|f|}{t}~d\mu  \\
$$

---

Another inequality is as follows:
$$
\mu\left(\{x\in X : |f(x)|\geq t\}\right)=\int_{X} \chi_A  ~d\mu \\
= \int_{X} \frac{t^2}{t^2}\chi_A ~d\mu \leq \int_{X} \frac{f^2}{t^2}\chi_A ~d\mu  \\
\leq \int_{X} \frac{f^2}{t^2}~d\mu  \\
$$

Comment: In the last step, you assume that $\chi_A ~d\$ is always 1 or 0, so you put \leq \

Comment: Exactly right! $\chi_A$ is either zero or one so it can be upper bounded by 1.

Comment: Another doubt I have is that in the first step you directly state that $$
\mu(A)=\int_{A} ~d\mu =\int_{X} \chi_A ~d\mu 
$$ but we can only use that when A is measurable. Do I have to prove this before?

Comment: $A$ is measurable because $f$ is measurable and $|f|\geq t$ is union of two Borel sets.

Comment: Now I have to conclude that the measure of A is going to be finite for every t. f is integrable when the integral absolute value of f is finite, so that divided by a positive number is going to be finite. Is that the answer?

Comment: If you want to prove the finite measure, then we should have $\int_X |f|d\mu<\infty$.